# How can I find the first repeated character in a user-entered string?

Tags: c

How can I find the first repeated character in a string?
If the input is "`abcdexyzbwqpoolj`", the 
output should be `b`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j;
char str[1000];

scanf("%s",str);//input the string
for( i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<strlen(str);j++)
    {
        if(str[i]==str[j])//compare
        {
            printf("%c",str[i]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is printing all the repeating characters, but I only want to print the first one. Please correct this code.

Comment: So finish your loop after the first print. Do you know how?

Comment: if input is codingghadd the out put should be g but using this code the output is gd i need only first repeating char

Comment: Also your solution is suboptimal. Can be done in O(n) if using array of 26 to mark which letter was seen before.

Comment: if input is coddenoww the output should be d that is the first repeating character but the output using this code is dw.

Comment: @lakshmichandhana is your keyboard broken?

Comment: A simple solution is to put `return 0;` just after the `printf`

Comment: Since you iterate the entire string each time round the loops anyway (strlen calls), I would not worry about minor optimizations:(

Comment: BTW, the O(n) I mentioned is actually O(1), as it will do 27 iterations at most.

Comment: In `"abba..."` is the first repeated character `'a'` or `'b'`? I'd say `'a'` ... just for fun

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exit the function you are in, including if it is the `main` function, then just do a `return`:

```
if(str[i]==str[j])//compare
{
    printf("%c",str[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

This will not work if you have code after the loop in the same function that needs to execute. You can use goto to exit a nested loop. Breaking out of nested loops is one of few acceptable usages of `goto`:

```
for( i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<strlen(str);j++)
    {
        if(str[i]==str[j])//compare
        {
            printf("%c",str[i]);
            goto done;
        }
    }
}
done:
    ;
```

If it is a non-nested loop, then use `break`

Comment: or simply do a `return 0;`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to return as soon as you find the first repeated character:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i,j;
  char str[1000];

  scanf("%s",str); // input the string
  for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    for (j = i + 1; str[j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
      if (str[i] == str[j]) // compare
      {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you already have an extra check, why not to use it to break out of the loop? The solution is suboptimal already, why make it even worse?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm normally against premature optimization, but in this case I have to agree. Probably it does not matter in this case, but yeah.

Comment: @klutt I wouldn't call it premature. If my intuitive estimation correct, for random strings it will make the difference between O(n) and O(n^2) in average.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm being diplomatic. A more honest term than "premature optimization" would be "bad design" ;)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Not sure this is even worth working on anymore but I fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: Showing working code is always crucial — no-one can tell what the prior version was going to produce because it would quite likely have been reading out of bounds of the array, or skipping parts of the input because there was a null byte early in the data before the `scanf()` overwrote it.  Perpetually polishing is another issue altogether.  You might decide to flag the commentary as "No longer needed" (use "Needs moderator attention" and start "No longer needed" — and explain that the comments are all no longer needed).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Done. Also, this solution is obviously less than ideal (as others have already pointed out). Would it be bad form to modify my solution to incorporate theirs? For example, printing the duplicate character inside the if-statement and then returning?

Comment: Not bad form — entirely up to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177042/discussion-between-alex-johnson-and-jonathan-leffler).

Answer (score 1):

Another array could be used to count characters as they occur. A match is when the count is no longer zero. In `abcdedcba` it will report `d` is the first character that matches.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void) {
    char all[256] = { 0};
    char text[1000] = { 0};
    int comp = 0;
    if ( fgets ( text, sizeof text, stdin)) {
        for ( comp = 0; text[comp]; ++comp) {
            if ( all[(unsigned char)text[comp]]) {
                printf ( "matched \'%c\'\n", text[comp]);
                break;
            }
            all[(unsigned char)text[comp]]++;
        }
    }
    else {
        fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
    }
    if ( !text[comp]) {
        printf ( "no matched characters\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the cast needs to be to `(unsigned char)` rather than just `(unsigned)` as a negative character code would be converted to a negative `int` before being converted to `unsigned`, which would access the array out of bounds.  Try: `#include <stdio.h>` – `int main(void) { char c = '\xD9'; unsigned u1 = (unsigned)c; unsigned u2 = (unsigned char)c; printf("\\x%.2X = (unsigned) %u = (unsigned char) %u\n", c, u1, u2); return 0; }`  On a Mac, I get the output: `\xFFFFFFD9 = (unsigned) 4294967257 = (unsigned char) 217`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple code solution

Here's a (not worse than) linear-time answer based on the hint first [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51596516/if-input-is-abcdexyzbwqpoolj-the-output-should-be-b-find-first-repeating-charact?noredirect=1#comment90159081_51596516) on by [Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253229/eugene-sh):

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[1000];
    char map[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = { 0 };

    if (scanf("%999s", str) == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            int n = (unsigned char)str[i];
            if (map[n]++ != 0)
            {
                printf("first duplicate: %c\n", str[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This keeps a record of each byte already seen in the `map` array, and simply breaks the loop when a duplicate character (not just letter) is found.  This has various merits, including:

- linear (O(N)) execution time
- not breaking nested loops (because there's no nesting)
- not scanning the whole input if there are duplicates at the start
- not using `strlen()` in the loop condition (that could make the original code more complex than O(N²) if the optimizer doesn't detect that `strlen()` could be called just once)

Its main demerit is that it says nothing if no duplicate is found.  If that's not acceptable, add a flag that is initially false, is set to true when the `break` is executed, and is tested after the loop.  Alternatively, instead of a `break`, the code could use `return 0;` to exit the program after printing the duplicate, and could print a 'no duplicates' message and exit with failure at the end.

#### O(N) linear vs O(1) constant search time

Since the total search space is 255 bytes (because a null byte isn't counted as a duplicatable character), there is room to argue that rather than being O(N) linear time, it is O(1) constant time.  If the input is only lower-case non-alphabetic, then there must be a duplicate if there are 27 characters in the input.  If the input is not so constrained, then there will be a duplicate within the first 256 bytes (it is less than that since `scanf()` and `%s` stop reading at the first white space, so there can't be any white space characters to repeat).  The Big-O notation is for the asymptotic run time, and neither 27 nor 256 is very large, so it can be argued that the run time is O(1).

Comment: As I commented later, it's O(1) in fact.

Comment: Hmmm: I suppose so — neither 27 nor 256 (null bytes aren't counted) is a particularly large 'asymptote', so I suppose you're right.

Comment: It occurs to me that we're discounting the O(N) behaviour of `scanf()`, though since that input is limited too (now I've added the `999`), the upper bound there is still rather finite (999 is not a very close approach to infinity).

Comment: Well, I am not considering IO, just the algorithm. I don't think we can take IO in these terms, as it is not taking in account the human part complexity :)

Comment: Hmmm... does it matter whether this is O(1), O(n) or something else? I would expect the IO (i.e. scanf) to be so slow that the performance of the remaining code is irrelevant.

Comment: @4386427: In the context of this main program, the I/O dominates, and the Big-O notation value isn't all that important.  However, if you abstract the code into a function, then the code in the question is O(N²) at best (it could be O(N⁴) if the `strlen()` calls are executed on each loop iteration), and then it could begin to matter. Again, if the alphabet is small (26, 52, 62 characters), it probably doesn't matter; if the alphabet is bigger, it matters more. In general, linear algorithms are preferable to quadratic (let alone quartic) algorithms — which is a reason for adding this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[100];
    char a[100];
    scanf("%s",s);
    int flag=0;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<strlen(a);j++)
        {
            if(s[i]==a[j])
            {
                printf("%c",s[i]);
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                a[j]=s[i];
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
        printf("null");
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Please add some text to your post, explaining how your code offers improvements over that in the other answers.